# I need a hint to model a modern heater radiator

Tags: modeling

[image: Two modules of the radiator]

Doing it in edit mode, start with a plane and then extrude them at all, use booleans..., the main stopper are the curved blades and how to combine them with the central vertical pipe and the cilinders... the image shows two modules, I only need a half module (mirror modifier and array will do the rest) I apologize if i'm asking this in a wrong way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the amount of detail you need, it is rather easy to model.
I made this in just a few minutes (took me longer to write this answer).
[image: modeled in blender]

First break down the object, and think about each part.
There are nine fins (and it looks the same front and back), so use a plane Solidify, Array and Mirror modifiers to make those.

The bottom corner is beveled on all of them, so before applying the array modifier bevel the bottom vertex <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.
[image: a plane with array, mirror, and solidify modifiers]

Add a plane as a separate object to use as the back.
[image: back plane in wireframe]

Back in the original object, now with the mirror modifier applied, start editing the individual fins. Move the center three up. Extrude the bends for the inside ones, and extrude the outside frame.
[image: more pieces of the model coming along]

Just add two cylinders, and bevel the remaining corners, and tweak the shape.

It really pretty easy. Use the modifiers! Solidify and Mirror are a must for this object.